# Nested lists - selecting path using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have Javascript function that is adding css class "current" to selected link `<a>`. This function looks like that:

```
function markActiveLink() {
    var path = location.pathname;
    var links = null;
    if (path) {
        links = $("a[href^='" + path + "']");
    } else {
        links = $("a[href='/']");
    }
    links.parents("li").each(function () {
        $(this).addClass("current");
    });
}
```

And I have nested list wchich looks similar to that list:

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#a">menu item</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#aa">menu item</a> </li>
            <li><a href="#ab">menu item</a></li>            
            <li><a href="#">menu item</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
        <li><a href="#a">menu item</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#aa">menu item</a> </li>
            <li><a href="#ab">menu item</a></li>            
            <li><a href="#">menu item</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I want to add class "current" (using Javascript function) not to link `<a>` like it is now working but to `<li>` element and it's parent `<li>`. So it would look like that:

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li class="current"><a href="#a">menu item</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#aa">menu item</a> </li>
            <li class="current"><a href="#ab">menu item</a></li>            
            <li><a href="#">menu item</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
        <li><a href="#a">menu item</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#aa">menu item</a> </li>
            <li><a href="#ab">menu item</a></li>            
            <li><a href="#">menu item</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**Question**: How can I modify my function `markActiveLink()` so that it would add class "current" both to `<li>` element and it's parent `<li>` element?

Any help here much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
links.parent().addClass('current')
     .closest('li').addClass('current');
```

[jQuery Docs](http://api.jquery.com/parent/)

Comment: @kritya, Except your solution doesn't add it to the parent and grandparent as requested :P...Don't try to change it now...just concede (and vote up) :)

Comment: I was typing my question :(.
GrandParent ? :O :O ill add it to grand grand parent :P

Comment: Your soultion is adding "current" class to all top level <li> elements. And I need only one of them (grandparent) to be selected.

Comment: @Cassandra, see above edit. Does that work for you? You want parent and grandparent, right?

Comment: Yes it works just as I want it to work. You don't even know how much time I spend on it already. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Use the `.parent()` api to do it
[Docs](http://api.jquery.com/parent/)
**EDIT**
Something like this:

```
$(this).parent().parent().addClass("current")
```

Comment: Your soultion is adding "current" class to all top level <li> elements. And I need only one of them (grandparent) to be selected. And the selected element <li> is not having "current" class.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me like it's working. I only changed the hrefs in your links so they wouldn't be duplicates and added some CSS to show the highlighted elements [in this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3BYwT/2/)